# MySql query to divide with another query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to combine the following queries and get the result datewise:

**Query1**

```
select  sum(Repeat_count) from
    (select cust_ph_no,count(cust_ph_no) as Repeat_Count
    from call_data    
    where date(call_start_date_time) = CURDATE()-1 
       and campaign_name = 'VT' and report_Id LIKE -2 
       and call_status_disposition not like 'supervised_transfer' 
       and campaign_type = 'IB'    
GROUP BY 1  
HAVING (Repeat_Count > 1))temp;
```

**Query2**

```
select 
    SUM(IF(call_status_disposition <> 'lt',1,0)) AS Offered
from call_data 
where date(call_start_date_time) = curdate()-1 and 
      campaign_name = 'VT' and 
     report_Id LIKE -2 and 
     call_status_disposition not like 'supervised_transfer' and campaign_type = 'IB';
```

Query1 Result ---> 350

Query2 Result ---> 1355

What I want is....a query which can divide Query1/Query2(350/1355=26%).

And also if I can get this date wise(currently I am using CURDATE()-1).

Date column is **call_start_date_time**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty simple.

If you have only one row in each row you can use the following construction:

```
select (select 1)/(select 2);

0.5000
```

Note, each sub-query must return only 1 row.

So, I tried to write you query:

```
select DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL @rownum + 1 day),
       (
            select  sum(Repeat_count) 
            from
              (select cust_ph_no,count(cust_ph_no) as Repeat_Count
              from call_data    
              where date(call_start_date_time) = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL @rownum + 1 day)
                      and campaign_name = 'VT' and report_Id LIKE -2 
                      and call_status_disposition not like 'supervised_transfer' 
                      and campaign_type = 'IB'    
            GROUP BY 1  
            HAVING (Repeat_Count > 1))temp
       )/
       (
       select 
            SUM(IF(call_status_disposition <> 'lt',1,0)) AS Offered
            from call_data 
            where date(call_start_date_time) = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL @rownum + 1 day) and
                campaign_name = 'VT' and 
                report_Id LIKE -2 and 
                call_status_disposition not like 'supervised_transfer' and campaign_type = 'IB'
       ),
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
from information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS 
       join (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Pay attention on the following points:

```
DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL @rownum + 1 day)
```

Actual date, I used current date for example. You can select something else.

```
INTERVAL @rownum + 1 day
```

Allows to select next date for new row.

I don't have you data and this query can have some errors, because I can not check it.

Comment: This work perfectly when I need output for only one day but I want output to be datewise.